# Removing code from code behind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to move some of the code behind in my project to a separate class. The part that I am interested in moving is the GetData method. I would like to move it out of my code behind to a separate class called DataAccess. I would appreciate your assistance. Thanks!

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Contact_Interests
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel> myAggLabels;

    public ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel> AggLabels
    {
        get { return myAggLabels; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ContactList> myContactLists;

    public IEnumerable<ContactList> ContactLists
    {
        get { return myContactLists; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        GetData();
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        myAggLabels = new ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel>();
        myContactLists = new ObservableCollection<ContactList>();

        DB2Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new DB2Connection("XXXX;");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException);
        }

        //get all contactLists and their labels
        DB2Command command = new DB2Command("SQL SELECT statement");
        command.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();

        //get all labels from database
        using (DB2DataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                AggregatedLabel aggLabel = new AggregatedLabel();

                aggLabel.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_ID"]);
                aggLabel.Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString();

                myAggLabels.Add(aggLabel);

            }
        }
        //Add unique contactLists to dictionary
        Dictionary<int, ContactList> myContactDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ContactList>();

        using (DB2DataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
               int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CONTACT_LIST_ID"]);

                if (!myContactDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
                {

                    ContactList contactList = new ContactList();

                    contactList.ContactListID = id;
                    contactList.ContactListName = dr["CONTACT_LIST_NAME"].ToString();
                    contactList.AggLabels = new ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel>()
                {
                    new AggregatedLabel()
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_ID"]),
                        Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString()
                    }

                };
                    myContactDictionary.Add(id, contactList);
                }
                else
                {
                    //populate existing contact lists with remaining labels
                    ContactList contactList = myContactDictionary[id];

                    contactList.AggLabels.Add
                    (
                        new AggregatedLabel() 
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_ID"]),
                            Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString()
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        //add to observable collection      
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ContactList> contactKeyValue in myContactDictionary)
        {
            ContactList contactList = contactKeyValue.Value;

            myContactLists.Add(contactList);
        }

        conn.Close();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a class for this, and just move all of your code into it.

Then create an instance of the class and set it as the `DataContext` for this Window.

If your interested in the mechanics, and the motivation (other than just pulling out of code behind), you can refer to my [series on MVVM](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/), or one of the many great [MVVM introductions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

---

For example, your code above could be:

```
namespace Contact_Interests
{
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel // : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel> myAggLabels;

        public ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel> AggLabels
        {
            get { return myAggLabels; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ContactList> myContactLists;

        public IEnumerable<ContactList> ContactLists
        {
            get { return myContactLists; }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            GetData();

            // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
        }

        public void GetData()
        {
            myAggLabels = new ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel>();
            myContactLists = new ObservableCollection<ContactList>();

            DB2Connection conn = null;
            try
            {
                conn = new DB2Connection("XXXX;");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException);
            }

            //get all contactLists and their labels
            DB2Command command = new DB2Command("SQL SELECT statement");
            command.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();

            //get all labels from database
            using (DB2DataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    AggregatedLabel aggLabel = new AggregatedLabel();

                    aggLabel.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_ID"]);
                    aggLabel.Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString();

                    myAggLabels.Add(aggLabel);

                }
            }
            //Add unique contactLists to dictionary
            Dictionary<int, ContactList> myContactDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ContactList>();

            using (DB2DataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                   int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CONTACT_LIST_ID"]);

                    if (!myContactDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
                    {

                        ContactList contactList = new ContactList();

                        contactList.ContactListID = id;
                        contactList.ContactListName = dr["CONTACT_LIST_NAME"].ToString();
                        contactList.AggLabels = new ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel>()
                    {
                        new AggregatedLabel()
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_ID"]),
                            Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString()
                        }

                    };
                        myContactDictionary.Add(id, contactList);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //populate existing contact lists with remaining labels
                        ContactList contactList = myContactDictionary[id];

                        contactList.AggLabels.Add
                        (
                            new AggregatedLabel() 
                            {
                                ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_ID"]),
                                Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString()
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }

            //add to observable collection      
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ContactList> contactKeyValue in myContactDictionary)
            {
                ContactList contactList = contactKeyValue.Value;

                myContactLists.Add(contactList);
            }

            conn.Close();        
        }
    }
}
```

Then, your main window becomes:

```
namespace Contact_Interests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
         public MainWindow()
         {
              InitializeComponent();
              this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like MVVM is the way forward. However I have not fully got my head around it so will continue to read up about it. Would it be possible for you to assist me with refactoring the code I have supplied, I guess it would make more sense when I am looking at code which I have written myself. Thank you.

Comment: Basically, just put ALL of this code into a different class (other than the constructor), and in the constructor, add : this.DataContext = new MyNewClass();   That will separate this out for you...

Comment: @Ben: I'd really recommend the series I linked to - if you've done Windows Forms development in the past, my series seems to be one of the easier transitions for people (from the feedback I've gotten)

Comment: Thanks Reed i'll mark this as an answer, although setting the dataContext in the constructor does not seem to work for me. Could you show me what this section should look like. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

As Reed suggested, you should definitely look into the MVVM pattern if you're planning on working with WPF. The pattern is integral to how WPF works.

Heres an introduction to MVVM that really helped me understand the different aspects of the pattern.

http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650
http://www.lab49.com/files/videos/Jason%20Dolinger%20MVVM.wmv

The video starts off with something similar to what you have, in that you have the processing code in the code-behind, Jason then proceeds to move code into separate classes and the end product is a clean separation of presentation and data processing.